Error: Class "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception" not found
I have a (maybe dumb) question. Since I am a newbie and tried several solutions already I am now here to ask for your help regarding a script.
I am using this script to generate LetsEncrypt certificates. It is working for over five years but today I was prompted the following message via terminal during the order:
550: Failed to spawn mail-process (ec:16) Error: Class "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception" not found
This is the relevant part of the script triggered:
###sending it as email:
##########################################################
# sendCertificate
##########################################################
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
include('PHPMailer.php');

function sendCertificate($myemail) {
    global $argv;
    global $account_number;

    $email = new PHPMailer();
    $email->setFrom($myemail); //Name is optional
    $email->Subject   = 'ssl certificate files';
    $email->Body      = "
https://kis.hosteurope.de/administration/webhosting/admin.php?menu=6&mode=ssl_list&wp_id=$account_number
Zertifikat: fullchain.pem
Key: cert_private_key.pem
";

    $email->addAddress($myemail);
    
    $file_to_attach = __DIR__ . '/'.$argv[3];
    $email->addAttachment($file_to_attach , $argv[3]);
    $file_to_attach = __DIR__ . '/fullchain.pem';
    $email->addAttachment($file_to_attach , 'fullchain.pem');
    
    $sent = $email->send();
    if($sent) {
        echo "sending certificates by mail ... OK\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "sending certificates by mail ... ERROR\n";
        print_r( error_get_last() );
    }
}
sendCertificate($argv[1]);


?>

I am on a webspace hosted on GoDaddy btw. Server is PHP 8.1. The Script was not changed since it worked some weeks ago.
Thank you!
Best
I tried to update the PHPMailer.php to most recent one.

If you're a newbie, the absolute number one rule to follow is read the docs. In this case it's because you didn't read what it said in the readme about how to load PHPMailer classes. Here the solution is to load the class that it's missing (use statements define local namespace aliases, they don't load anything). The next most useful thing to learn in PHP is how to use composer. Doing either of these things would have avoided you getting stuck on this.

Installing libraries with Composer is by far the easiest way to do it. Even if you are learning and want to understand how things work under the hood, it's much better to do so with your own code, where you can try manual includes first and write a class autoloader second; you won't learn anything valuable doing that with third-party code.

I appreciate you took time to answer here. As I said it worked before, thats why I was confused. Anyway, of course I read about the changes but I am unable with my skills to fix it. Now I did it with GPT :)

I solved the Problem by updating the PHP Mailer, creating a new SMTP account and updated the script:
    // Manually loading the necessary PHPMailer classes
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';

function sendCertificate($myemail) {
    global $argv;
    global $account_number;
    global $domain_id;

    $email = new PHPMailer();

    try {
        //Server settings
        $email->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $email->Host       = '+++';      // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $email->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $email->Username   = '+++';                       // SMTP username
        $email->Password   = '+++;                           // SMTP password
        $email->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
        $email->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        // Recipients and content
        $email->setFrom($myemail); // Name is optional
        $email->Subject = '+++';
        $email->Body = "
https://kis.hosteurope.de/administration/webhosting/admin.php?menu=6&wp_id=$account_number&mode=sslupload&v_id=$domain_id
Certificate: fullchain.pem
Key: cert_private_key.pem
";
        $email->addAddress($myemail);

        $file_to_attach = __DIR__ . '/' . $argv[3];
        $email->addAttachment($file_to_attach, $argv[3]);
        $file_to_attach = __DIR__ . '/fullchain.pem';
        $email->addAttachment($file_to_attach, 'fullchain.pem');

        if ($email->send()) {
            echo "Sending certificates by email ... OK\n";
        } else {
            echo "Sending certificates by email ... ERROR\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Sending certificates by email ... ERROR: ", $email->ErrorInfo, "\n";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "General error: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}

sendCertificate($argv[1]);

